# Testing Kotlin Flow.combine with unending flows

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following test

```kotlin
@Test
fun combineUnendingFlows() = runBlockingTest {

    val source1 = flow {
        emit("a")
        emit("b")
        suspendCancellableCoroutine { /* Never complete. */ }
    }

    val source2 = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    val combinations = mutableListOf<String>()

    combine(source1, source2) { first, second -> "$first$second" }
        .onEach(::println)
        .onEach(combinations::add)
        .launchIn(this)

    advanceUntilIdle()

    assertThat(combinations).containsExactly("a1", "b1", "b2", "b3")
}
```

The assertion succeeds, however the test fails with the exception:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: Test finished with active jobs
```

I know this is contrived, and we could easily make this pass by ensuring that `source1` completes, but I'm wondering why it fails? Is `runBlockingTest` the wrong approach for testing never-ending flows?

(This is with coroutines `1.4.0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of the issue appears to be that `runBlockingTest` (probably rightly), expects there to be no running jobs by the time it goes to finish.

This would be fine if we could explicitly cancel the scope provided by `runBlockingTest`, however attempting to call `.cancel()` on that scope throws an exception.

There's more discussion on the problem in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1531).

In this contrived example, it would be simple enough get a reference to the `Job` created by `launchIn()` and cancel it before the test closes.

More elaborate scenarios could either catch `UncompletedCoroutinesError` and ignore it since they expect there to be unfinished coroutines, or they could create a new child `CoroutineScope` to explicitly cancel. In this example, that would look like

```kotlin
@Test
fun combineUnendingFlows() = runBlockingTest {
    val job = Job()
    val childScope = CoroutineScope(this.coroutineContext + job)

    val source1 = flow {
        emit("a")
        emit("b")
        suspendCancellableCoroutine { /* Never complete. */ }
    }

    val source2 = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    val combinations = mutableListOf<String>()

    combine(source1, source2) { first, second -> "$first$second" }
        .onEach(::println)
        .onEach(combinations::add)
        .launchIn(childScope)

    advanceUntilIdle()
    assertThat(combinations).containsExactly("a1", "b1", "b2", "b3")
    job.cancel()
}
```